# What the matter between Zygote and UI thread of Android

Tags: java, android

As you see, I want to know how the ActivityThread is called? How does Zygote process use this class? Thinks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on writing a good question and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the source code of ActivityThread.java and ZygoteInit. These are the two classes responsible for creating both the process and the main thread for your or any, application. Specifically look at the method [ZygoteInit#main(String[])](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/19bb1a0b99afcbb2ee4cb0f5b5d92011e0cc146f/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteInit.java#L681) it is what's responsible for calling [ActivityThread#main(String[])](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/19bb1a0b99afcbb2ee4cb0f5b5d92011e0cc146f/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#L6475) which actually [prepares the "main" Looper](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/19bb1a0b99afcbb2ee4cb0f5b5d92011e0cc146f/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#L6494) which all app events are executed including app drawing.